# EF4 POCO Many To One

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, poco

I'm trying to have one POCO objects containing 2 tables.

I have 2 tables :

```
-Customer (#CustomerId, Name, CustomerProperties)
-CustomerExtended (#ExtendedId, #CustomerId, extendedProperties)
```

And I would have one POCO object:
`Customer`

```
- CustomerId
- Name
- CustomerProperties
- ExtendedProperties
```

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code-first solution (without fluent code).

```
public class Customer
{
  public int CustomerId { get; set;}
 //navigation
  public List<CustomerProperty> CustomerProperties { get; set;}
}

public class CustomerProperty
{
  public int CustomerPropertyId { get; set;}
  //navigation
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

It will pruduce two tables  CustomerProperties and Customers, and you can access CustomerProperties from the Customer instance.

Comment: @ I am learning somethings from your answer. How do I show the properties of CustomerProperty from my Customer insatnce? i am only able to show Customer property from the CustomerProperty instance?